# access to vhost refused for guest, with the MassTransit Sample-RequestResponse sample

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using the default configuration on latest RabbitMQ server (guest is admin) but I get the next exception when I run the [RequestResponse](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse) sample.

> OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=530, text="NOT_ALLOWED - access to vhost 'test' refused for user 'guest'", classId=10, methodId=40, cause=

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample is correct. The setting in `App.config` is:

```
<add key="RabbitMQHost" value="rabbitmq://localhost/test"/>
```

It means that MT will try connecting to the local instance, and `test` virtual host. Out of the box RabbitMQ has no virtual hosts configured and this is why you are getting this exception.

What you could have done is, using the management plugin:

1. Add the `test` virtual host to your RabbitMQ server configuration
2. Add full permissions to that virtual host to your `guest` user

And then it will work with the `App.config` without changes.

Comment: how doi add full permissions for `guest`?